# Nested function not working - Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: python

I am writing a tic tac toe game in Python with a function called `winning` I call in several different places. When I call it from the `winning_human` function it seems like it's working fine, but when I use it for the computer (the 'AI') part, it returns `false` in all cases, and I really cannot figure out why. Any ideas?

```
import pprint

class Game(object):

    def __init__(self, player, board):
        self.player = player        
        self.board = board

    def print_board(self):
        print(self.board[1]+ '|' + self.board[2]+ '|' + self.board[3])
        print('-----')
        print(self.board[4]+ '|' + self.board[5]+ '|' + self.board[6])
        print('-----')
        print(self.board[7]+ '|' + self.board[8]+ '|' + self.board[9])

    def play(self,board):
        self.print_board()
        print('specify your move (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)')
        self.move = int(input())
        valid_moves = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        if self.move not in valid_moves:
            print('you did not specify a valid move, please try again!')
            self.play(self.board)
        if self.board[self.move] != ' ':
            print ('you can not play that space, it is taken')
            self.play(self.board)        
        self.board[self.move]='X'
        self.print_board()
        self.winning_human('X', self.board)


    def winning(self, player, board):
        return ((self.board[1]==self.player and self.board[2]==self.player and self.board[3]==self.player)or         
        (self.board[4]==self.player and self.board[5]==self.player and self.board[6]==self.player)or
        (self.board[7]==self.player and self.board[8]==self.player and self.board[9]==self.player)or         
        (self.board[1]==self.player and self.board[4]==self.player and self.board[7]==self.player)or    
        (self.board[2]==self.player and self.board[5]==self.player and self.board[8]==self.player)or
        (self.board[3]==self.player and self.board[6]==self.player and self.board[9]==self.player)or
        (self.board[1]==self.player and self.board[5]==self.player and self.board[9]==self.player)or
        (self.board[3]==self.player and self.board[5]==self.player and self.board[7]==self.player))

    def winning_human(self, player, board):
        if self.winning('X', self.board):
            True
            print('you won') 
        else:
            print('the game shall cont (winning human funct).')
            self.comp_play('O', self.board)

    def comp_play(self, player, board):
        for i in range(1,10):
            if self.board[i] == ' ':
                self.board[i] = 'O'
                if self.winning('O',self.board):
                    self.end_game(self)
                else:
                    self.board[i] = ' '

        #check if player can win in next move, block if so
        #check if middle is free
        #check if corner is free       


    def end_game(self):
        self.print_board()
        print('Thanks for playing, the computer beat you')          

    theBoard = {1:' ', 2:'O', 3:'O', 4: ' ', 5:'X', 6: 'X', 7:' ', 8:' ', 9:' '}
    g=Game('X', theBoard)
    g.play(theBoard)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the player to check for (`X` or `O`) to the `winning` method, but then inside that method you only use `self.player` (which is always `X`).